# The sign of a determinant?

Tags: functions, determinant, continued-fractions, mean-value-theorem, hankel-matrices

Let $$A = [a_{ij}] = \begin{bmatrix} 1& 1/2! & 1/3!\\ 1/2! & 1/3!& 1/4!\\ 1/3!& 1/4! & 1/5!\end{bmatrix}.$$

Let $A^{\circ r}=[a_{ij}^r]$ for $r>0$.  We need to prove that $\det(A^{\circ r})$ is negative for every $r>1$. One observation is that $\det(A^{\circ r})$ is negative at $r = 1$, is increasing when $r>1$, and tends to zero as $r \rightarrow \infty$. This will serve the purpose.

**Que:** How can we show that $\det(A^{\circ r})$ is increasing when $r>1$?

The matrix $A$ is Hankel, is it helpful to prove this?

Any help or hint is appreciated.

Comment: This probably isn't what the question is looking for, but have you tried just writing the determinant out?

Comment: Computing the determinant and clearing denominators, we see that it is enough to show that $40^r+18^r+15^r-2\cdot 30^r-12^r$ is positive. For $r>4$, we use the inequality $40^r-3\cdot 30^r>0$; for $r\leq 3$, we use direct computation. This is not what you are looking for, but I do think it's easy to argue the increasing part once you get the explicit formula.